# Why are static_placeholders not shown on the structure sidebar on DjangoCMS 4.x

Tags: django-cms

After starting a new project in DjangoCMS 4.x, I added a `static_placeholder` as usual for the footer on my template and it didn't appear anymore on the structure sidebar, which were normally placed underneath the normal placeholders on DjangoCMS 3.x.

It took me a long time to figure out (actually after I opened a new bug on github and a dev explained it to me), that this is no bug or missing behaviour, but just the fact that static-placeholders got replaced by aliases on 4.x.

Below is my own answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DjangoCMS 4.x static placeholders were replaced by aliases to be able to support versioning as with the normal pages. You can add a `footer` alias to the template like described on the docs:
https://django-cms-docs.readthedocs.io/en/staging/introduction/02-templates_placeholders.html#static-aliases

```html
<!-- some CMS template, e.g. default.html, or directly on base.html -->
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags djangocms_alias_tags %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% page_attribute "page_title" %}</title>
        {% render_block "css" %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% cms_toolbar %}
        {% placeholder "content" %}
        <footer>
            {% static_alias "footer" %}
        </footer>
        {% render_block "js" %}
    </body>
</html>
```

After that, you can go to `Aliases...` and create/edit a new draft as you would with a page.

And of course, you must first publish a version first in order to see the footer if you're not logged in as an admin ;-)

And, as a side note, **it's normal that they still don't appear on the structure sidebar underneath the "normal" placeholders when editing a page**. Instead, they get their "own structure sidebar", when editing an alias. Which also didn't seem that obvious for me at the beginning.